# TS Errors when declaring types on useContext Provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having difficulty satisfying TS when setting up a `useContext` state provider

Here I define the interface

```
interface UserProvider {
  user: UserWithDetails | null
  setUser: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<UserWithDetails>> | null
}
export const UserContext = createContext<UserProvider | {}>({})
```

Here I pass my values:

```
<UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
```

When trying to access my user in a component I receive the TS Error:

`Property 'user' does not exist on type '{} | UserProvider'.`

```
const { user } = useContext(UserContext) // Property 'user' does not exist on type '{} | UserProvider'.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `Context`'s type is `UserProvider | {}`, you can't be sure that `user` always exists when you use the context. One way to handle this is to use `null` instead and do a null check.

```
interface UserProvider {
  // your user provider
}
const UserContext = createContext<UserProvider | null>(null)

export const useUser = () => {
  const context = useContext(UserContext);

  // At this point, you don't know if your context is null or UserProvider

  if (context === null) {
    throw new Error("UserContext not provided");
  }

  // At this point, you know that your context has to be UserProvider

  return context;
};
```

Now, in your consumer, you can just consume the `useUser` hook instead of using the `UserContext` directly. This helps you to avoid null checks in your component.

```
// const { user } = useContext(UserContext)
const { user } = useUser()
```